# Handling '/' in url match in Django

Tags: python, regex, django

I am newbie to Django. I have written a function func() in views.py and corresponding regex for matching url in urls.py like following:

```
   (r'callfunc/(?P<param1>(\w+|\d+|\-){0,50})/(?P<param2>(\w+|\d+|\-){0,50})/$', 'func')
```

The problem is that sometimes '/' appears inside `param1` string and then regular expression matching fails in urls.py and application get stuck in the match. Is there any way to handle that properly so that even if any / comes inside param1, param1 get set properly?

Comment: add \/ to your regex to include it in the match.

Comment: This will not work because it is not necessary that / appears always inside params, it may appear, may not appear in that case url will be matched wrongly.

Comment: you can add `?` to make it optional

Comment: @Joy Is there any way you can design your application so that `/` does not appear in your parameters? This would be the best. Because if you do allow them then you lose the simplicity of being able to recognize at a glance how the URL is structured.

Comment: Yes I have handled it where it is called by base64 encoding the parameter where / may appear.

Answer (score 1):

How do you resolve an url with additional slash by hand? Let's say: `callfunc/foo/bar/baz/`. Does bar belong to param1 or param2? I think under this conditions it is not possible to distinguish the two params properly.

You can try to add a special disconnector: `r'^callfunc/(?P<param1>[\w\d\-/]{1,50})/special-versus/(?P<param2>[\w\d\-/]{1,50})/$'` It should be more or less impossible that the disconnector appears in on of your params.